# is there a way to use webpack defineplugin function in scss

Tags: reactjs, webpack-4

i want to use the defined plugin function image_path in scss can i use that
**webpack**

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                image_path: function(path) {
                    return '/images' + path;
                }
    })
```

**css** file is this

```
 .range {
                        &::-webkit-slider-thumb {
                            background-image: url($divum_image_path('practiceDifficultyRange.svg'));
                            background-size: 100rem;
                        }
                        &::-moz-range-thumb {
                            background: url($divum_image_path('practiceDifficultyRange.svg')) no-repeat;
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                image_path: function(path) {
                    return '/images' + path;
                }
    })
```

There is no way to use Image path variable in webpack

Comment: Should have been added as a comment instead.